# ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 95625 into shape (5625,) [python]

Tags: python, numpy

i want to see the residual plot with this code :

```
#calculate residuals
y_predict_train=simple_reg.predict(x_churn_train)
residual=y_churn_train - y_predict_train

#prepare dataframe
#1 predictor-->predictor vs residual
df_resid=pd.DataFrame({
'x_axis':x_churn_train.reshape(len(x_churn_train,)),
'residual':residual
})

#residual plot
sns.scatterplot(data=df_resid,x='x_axis',y='residual')
plt.axhline(0)
plt.show()
```

and the output :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_23548\962416463.py in <module>
  6 #1 predictor-->predictor vs residual
  7 df_resid=pd.DataFrame({
 ----> 8     'x_axis':x_churn_train.reshape(len(x_churn_train,)),
  9     'residual':residual
 10 })

 ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 95625 into shape (5625,)
```

and i check for the shape :

```
x_churn_train.shape,y_churn_train.shape
```

the output :

```
((5625, 17), (5625,))
```

how to fix this ? kindly help, thanks

Comment: Could you specify what you are trying to achieve? It seems like you are trying to use the whole train dataset as x-axis, but this is impossible due to dimentiality.Perhaps, you should choose something else as x-axis

Comment: @MariaKozlova i want to calculate the linear regression

Comment: I am not sure what "calculate the linear regression" means, but it seems like you've trained a model successfully and predicted the outputs in the first row. What do you want do do then? What do you want to plot?

Comment: @MariaKozlova i want to plot the residual

Comment: So the thing which causes the technical error - is that you are trying to fit your train dataset, which contains 17 columns and 5625 rows into a vector of size 5625. Which is clearly impossible.

One way to avoid that is to concatenate residuals to the train dataset as an additional column, for example, np.concatenate((x_churn_train, residual), axis=1).
However, after that you will most certainly get a problem with plotting, because you can't use 17-dimentional array as the x-axis. Here you should choose, what is the actual x-axis you want for your plot to make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Residuals (or errors) are computed between the true_values and the predicted values which in your case are y_churn_train and y_predict_train.
But what you did is reshaping your x_train data (that used to compute y_predict_train) to plot it with the residuals: `'x_axis':x_churn_train.reshape(len(x_churn_train,)),`
To solve it you simply need to use instead your true labels (y_churn_train)

`'x_axis':y_churn_train`

Edit: you could sure plot the true line to compare the residuals with, I mean the line with x and x are equal to y_churn_train.